# Eclipse Plugin - Get value of varibles/structures

Tags: java, eclipse, variables, plugins, structure

I want to develop a simple Eclipse Plugin to show the value of variables/stuctures in a view (like the variables plugin of Eclipse).

I have tried:

```
public static String getVariableValue(String name) {

    IValueVariable variable = VariablesPlugin.getDefault().getStringVariableManager().getValueVariable(name);
    if (variable != null) {
        return variable.getValue();
    }
    return "null"";
}
```

But this function even returns "null".

Have anyone a solution for me?

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: There are lots of different things called variables in Eclipse, which one do you mean?

Comment: I mean local variables, class/static variables...

Comment: The String Variables Manager is nothing to do with Java variables. If you mean Java variables in the program which is currently being debugged read something like [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugFramework/article.html)

Comment: Thanks, if you have additional website like this if would be very helpful. ;)